# ASP.NET Team Development without sharing source code

Tags: asp.net, development-environment

I have been developing ASP.NET websites solo but now I have 2 more developer and I want a tool to share project with them to create a team development environment but I don't want to share my source code with them for example my App_Code folder. I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Edition for development.

In other words i need an environment where i can share my project with other developers without my App_Code folder files.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: So ... the other developers should help you with the code without actually seeing it?

Comment: Convert app_code to a dll and share dll, then set up a source control.

Comment: Perhaps create a tool to encrypt your syntax and share that with them via the mainstream Source Control tools. This way they wont be able to see what you're coding... I don't know, I'm just imagining.

Comment: Not too sure how you imagine this will work. Even if you follow some of the suggestions below which require  you to migrate your app_code classes to a compiled library, most developers know how to decompile a dll using one of the many tools around. From a purely pragmatic point of view,  developers will need to understand, debug the code they are referencing.

Comment: Please clarify, are you trying to hide sensitive code from the other developers, or are you just looking for a way to prevent them from editing it? Clearly an application won't run without all of the code, so they at least need a compiled version of it to use to debug with. But it is also possible to share the code without accepting changes to it using source control.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to hide some sensitive code from the other developer included some classes and webservices

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a class library Project and add your sources to it.
2. Build it in release mode.
3. Add reference to the output DLL from the main project.

That's about it.

Regarding Source-Control Tools or TFS - it is good to have but will not replace the solution provided and is not focused to provide a solution to your problem.
It just a way to ease team development regarding versioning, bug tracking and etc..

Comment: It should be noted that this will require refactoring the solution in order to make the App_Code folder into a DLL. That could be a *lot* of work depending on how much code is in there. It also doesn't solve the entire problem (for example, the UI elements such as pages, images, and CSS won't be in the DLL). Using source control requires no refactoring at all and is ideal for "creating a 2 developer team environment" like the OP is asking for.

Comment: The OP wants to hide and protect his code from other developers prying eyes, he want his valuable code to be used as infrastructures only which he created after years of experience and effort. source control tools are not a solution to the specific problem the OP presents. any solution that will allow the developers to even see his code will not answer the problem.